# Android Stuio/gradle issue

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I am trying to import an existing project into Android Studio yet, for some reason I keep receiving this error message:

> Failed to refresh Gradle project 'bootstrapSample'
>              The project is using an unsupported version of the Android Gradle plug-in (0.6.3).
>   Quick Fix Failed
>              Unable to find any references to the Android Gradle plug-in in build.gradle files.
>              Please click the link to perform a textual search and then update the build files manually.

Can anyone elaborate further on what exactly this error message means and how to resolve it?

I am using Android Studio 0.4.5

Comment: Include build.gradle files generated in project directory in question.

Comment: There is a relation between the IDE and the gradle plugin used. Take a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21792598/relation-between-gradle-version-and-gradle-build-tool-version/21794625#21794625

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message means that the version of the Android plugin specified in the Gradle build script isn't compatible with the version expected by your version of Android Studio. You'll likely need to upgrade to a higher version of the Gradle Android plugin (by bumping the plugin's version number in the build script).