# Gradle version 1.6 is required. Current version is 1.8

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to build my Android app in Android Studio, but I have got the following error:

```
Gradle: A problem occurred evaluating project ':libraries:facebook'.
> Gradle version 1.6 is required. Current version is 1.8
```

How can I fix it? I don't know what is wrong with my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Update Android Studio to last release.
Then change:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8'
```

Modify your `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` to use the 1.10 version of Gradle.

Also to improve your script, you can change this line

```
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
```

with

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'  //or 19.0.1
```

There is a relation between IDE, gradle-plugin and the gradle version.

[relation between gradle version and gradle build tool version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21792598/relation-between-gradle-version-and-gradle-build-tool-version/21794625#21794625)