# Android Studio : Unable to find any references to the Android Gradle plug-in in build.gradle files

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, android-studio

I try to migrate from Eclipse to Android Studio and i'm getting this error in the android studio console :

```
13:52:44 Quick Fix Failed
         Unable to find any references to the Android Gradle plug-in in build.gradle files.
         Please click the link to perform a textual search and then update the build files manually.
```

Here is the content of my build.gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':ActionBar-PullToRefresh-master:ActionBar-PullToRefresh-master:library')
    compile project(':Crouton-master:Crouton-master:library')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

And here is my settings :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add this part to your script.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
    }
}
```

The value 0.8.+ depends by your Android Studio version and your gradle version.

[relation between gradle version and gradle build tool version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21792598/relation-between-gradle-version-and-gradle-build-tool-version/21794625#21794625)

Comment: Now, i get 'The project is using an unsupported version of the Android Gradle plug-in.'

Comment: You have to check the compatibility level between gradle-plugin and your IDE. Check the link above.

Comment: Thanks. But where i can change the version of the gradle plugin of my project ? (I use Android studio 0.4.6)

Comment: In your project: `gradle -> wrapper -> gradle-wrapper.properties` change to `gradle-1.10-bin.zip`

Comment: Also upgrade `Android Build Tools` to version 19.0.0+ in `SDK Manager`

Comment: @wawanopoulos use gradle plugin 0.8.+ and gradle 1.10 as suggested by Dima

Comment: Now i get : "The project is using an unsupported version of the Android Gradle plug-in" Where i can change the version of my Gradle plugin ? in my build.gradle file or in File => Settings => Gradle under Android Studio ?

Comment: You can change the gradle-plugin version in gradle script in classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'. 
You can change the gradle version in gradle -> wrapper -> gradle-wrapper.properties

Comment: Ok thanks. In my gradle folder, i d'ont have gradle-wrapper.properties. Only /bin /cache /deamon /doc /init ...