# Android Studio Gradle issue upgrading to version 0.5.0 - Gradle Migrating From 0.8 to 0.9 - Also Android Studio upgrade to 0.8.1

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After upgrade message states:

```
Failed to refresh Gradle project 'XXX'
The project is using an unsupported version of the Android Gradle plug-in (0.8.3).
Version 0.9.0 introduced incompatible changes in the build language.
Please read the migration guide to learn how to update your project.
```

Same kind of issue after upgrade to Android Studio to version >= 0.8.0

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To fix it, open file called `build.gradle` in the project root, and change gradle version there to 0.9.+.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}
```

To be repeated for each project ;(

If you then get a message like "*Unable to load class '`org.gradle.api.artifacts.result.ResolvedComponentResult`*".

Go to you `project_folder/gradle/wrapper` directory and edit `Unable to load class 'org.gradle.api.artifacts.result.ResolvedComponentResult'.` file changing the `distributionUrl` to

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip
```

After upgrade to version 0.8.1 (full download and copy SDK folder over), had to have new version of gradle installed by IDE (using the "Fix it" link a couple of time :S ), and modifing the "android" section of the gradle file in project folder from 19.0 to 19.1, as below:
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'android'

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
}
```

Comment: worked great. I only had to change the distributionURL

Comment: Oddly enough, changing `classpath` from `com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+` to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.0` fixed the Gradle sync for me.  Not sure why, or if it was coincidence.

Comment: close your project and re import the same project it fix automatically by android studio 0.5.1

Answer (score 61):

**Android Studio 0.5.0** requires **gradle-plugin 0.9.0**

The gradle-plugin **0.9.0** works with **Gradle 1.10 or Gradle 1.11**

Modify your build.gradle script as suggested by Cedric.

**There is a  relation between gradle-plugin and the gradle version.**
For example

**UPDATED TO 27/11/2015**:

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+   -> gradle 1.8
com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+   -> gradle 1.9
com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+   -> gradle 1.9/1.10
com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+   -> gradle 1.10/1.11
com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.+  -> gradle 1.10/1.11/1.12
com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+  -> gradle 1.10/1.11/1.12
com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+  -> gradle 1.10/1.11/1.12
com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.+  -> gradle 2.1
com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.+  -> gradle 2.1
com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.+   -> gradle 2.2.1-2.3
com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.+   -> gradle 2.2.1-2.3
com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.+   -> gradle 2.2.1+
com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.+   -> gradle 2.2.1+
com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.+   -> gradle 2.2.1+
com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.+   -> gradle 2.2.1+
com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.+   -> gradle 2.10.0+
```

You can find gradle version used in your project in the file `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

Also there is a  relation between gradle-plugin and the IDE version.

```
Android Studio 0.3.x  -> gradle-plugin 0.6
Android Studio 0.4.x  -> gradle-plugin 0.7
Android Studio 0.4.3+ -> gradle-plugin 0.8
Android Studio 0.5.x  -> gradle-plugin 0.9
Android Studio 0.5.8  -> gradle-plugin 0.9.+ or 0.10.+
Android Studio 0.5.9  -> gradle-plugin 0.9.+ or 0.10.4+
Android Studio 0.6.x  -> gradle-plugin 0.11.+
Android Studio 0.8.x  -> gradle-plugin 0.12.+
Android Studio 0.8.11+  -> gradle-plugin 0.13.+ / gradle-plugin 0.12.+
Android Studio 0.9.x  -> gradle-plugin 0.14.+
Android Studio 1.0.0  -> gradle-plugin 1.0.0
Android Studio 1.1.x  -> gradle-plugin 1.0.0/ 1.1.x / 1.2.x
Android Studio 1.2.x  -> gradle-plugin 1.0.0/ 1.1.x / 1.2.x
Android Studio 1.3.x  -> gradle-plugin 1.0.0/ 1.1.x / 1.2.x / 1.3.x 
Android Studio 1.4.x  -> gradle-plugin 1.0.0/ 1.1.x / 1.2.x / 1.3.x 
Android Studio 1.5.x  -> gradle-plugin 1.0.0/ 1.1.x / 1.2.x / 1.3.x / 1.5.x
Android Studio 2.0.x  -> gradle-plugin 2.0.0

 Also gradle 1.12 requires Android Studio 0.5.8+
```

For updated news you can check this link: http://tools.android.com/recent
For updated doc about the gradle plugin [check here](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/revisions/gradle-plugin.html).

If you change your plugin version, check compatibility, and then click sync project with your gradle files.It will download a new plugin version if you need it.

Comment: Thanks for listing these relationships! I've been searching and am really surprised I haven't been able to find this info concisely presented on http://www.gradle.org/ or http://developer.android.com/. Considering the multitude of questions we see regarding missmatching of these versions I'm surprised this info is not front and center on one of these sites!

Comment: Thanks for explaining mate, but im having a problem with gradle 2.0. I use 0.12.+ but keep getting error sying " Please use version 1.10." Cant find why its asking for 1.10!

Comment: @Kangars 0.12 doesn't support gradle 2.0 in my experience.

Comment: Gabriele Marriotti Thats possibly why its been complaining about it. I raised a question but seems like it is the case! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24289410/gradle-version-1-10-is-required-current-version-is-2-0

Comment: Thanks this was super helpful, I am on the latest studio and version and using this in my gradle wrapper: 
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip

Comment: Thanks this helped me get the project files in onder after upgrading AS. I use AS 0.8.9 so i updated my project to use `gradle-plugin 0.12.2` in `build.gradle` and therefor `gradle 1.12` in `gradle-wrapper.properties`.

... After every Android Studio upgrade i have to wrestle with Gradle when opening older projects, this not being prominently documented i dont understand.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error, but already had

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
```

set like this, as Cedric Simon suggested.
Thanks to the comment of mattblang, I tried to change it to 0.9.0 and refreshed it

for those who don't know, where the refresh button is, look below:

[image]

Afterwards I tried what happens when I change it back to 0.9.+ and refresh again...and it still works.

**So I assume, only pressing the refresh button would have sufficed.**

Answer (score 2):

I faced Same problem Migrating into gradle version 1.0.0.. This solution helps me and save the date..

**Update Plugin and Gradle Version Numbers**

The Android Gradle plugin version is typically listed in the top level **build.gradle** file in the project, and can be updated as follows:

Let me consider i have version 0.8.. show my build.gradle(project root folder/build.gradle) shows

> dependencies {
>          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
>        }

remove the old version(0.8) and add new version 1.0.0 like this

> dependencies {
>           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
>        }

And also change the ***gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties***:

remove the old distributionUrl and add new url

> distributionUrl=http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip

and change the runProguard in project root/app/build.gradle

**BEFORE:**

> buildTypes {
>           release {
>               runProguard true
>               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
>           }
>       }

**AFTER:**

> buildTypes {
>           release {
>               minifyEnabled true
>               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
>           }
>       }

For more information : [Migrating gradle Project(click here)](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-to-1-0-0)

Answer (score 0):

The most simple Android project has the following build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"
}
```

There are 3 main areas to this Android build file:

[new-build-system user-guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide)

Answer (score 0):

When I updated to Android Studio 1.0 I found that I need to update to use 1.0.0 version of gradle.

I had

```
  dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc2'
```

I changed it to remove the "-rc2"

```
  dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio version 1.0.2
The idea of tight coupling between IDE version and build version is bad.

Android Studio 1.0.2. 
Gralde plugin 1.0.+
gradle.properties, distribution URL=http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-bin.zip

Answer (score -1):

hmm I'm getting this error when I try to add this dependency.

Error:(22) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+] on project ':app'.

Ok solved it. This line should be part of the build.gradle "in the project root" as stated above, but I did not recognize. Updating the Build tools to 19.03 actually inserted it in automatically.