# Incorrect Gradle version for Android Studio project

Tags: android, gradle

I am using the latest version of Android Studio and have installed the latest version of Gradle from Gradle's website. I then imported some Android sample apps but the build generates an error that reads:

> Gradle version 1.10 is required. Current version is 2.1.

I have no idea where it is getting the version 1.10 from. If I open the gradle-wrapper.properties file, I have:

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-bin.zip

I have this problem with every sample I open. Why isn't Gradle using the version I installed? The GRADLE_HOME environment variable is set to the path of the latest version of Gradle.

Even if I run gradlew to force a download of the version of Gradle needed, I still get this error. One post here in SO is:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23466323/753632

meaning that a specific version of Gradle is required for a specific version of the Android Gradle Plugin, but this was posted some time ago and it isn't clear whether this is an issue anymore.

Comment: In a build.gradle file, do you have something like classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.+'?

Comment: I have 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'

Comment: So try to use 0.13.+

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling gradle and deleting the .gradle folder and then let android studio download gradle instead of installing it manually from the gradle website.

Answer (score 0):

Try clean and rebuild it will ok most of time.

And if you want to update the version to the latest.

You can try [andle](https://github.com/Jintin/andle)

Simple three step to update all project at once.

**1. install:**

```
    $ sudo pip install andle
```

**2. set sdk:**

```
    $ andle setsdk -p <sdk_path>
```

**3. update depedency:**

```
    $ andle update -p <project_path> [--dryrun] [--remote] [--gradle]
```

--dryrun: only print result in console

--remote: check version in jcenter and mavenCentral

--gradle: check gradle version

See https://github.com/Jintin/andle for more information