# Why am I getting Execution error `Could not find property` bootClasspath

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm getting this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':ProjectName:compileUniversalDebugJava'.
> Could not find property 'bootClasspath' on com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension_Decorated@26fd94a1.
```

Why is that?

I'm building Android app with gradle on Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I had to update `com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.+` instead of `com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+`. Here in my `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.+'
    ...
}
```

Comment: Which version of gradle are you using? and AS?

Comment: Now I don't have this issue any more and I'm using Gradle 2.2.1 and AS 1.2.1.1. As I wrote upgrade to gradle build tools to 0.10.+ was enough to fix this issue.

Comment: AS 1.2.1 shoud work with gradle plugin 1.x. Pay attention to use 0.10.+. Check the dependecies. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252956/android-studio-gradle-issue-upgrading-to-version-0-5-0-gradle-migrating-from-0/22256954#22256954