# Gradle version 1.10 is required. Current version is 2.0

Tags: android, maven, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am trying to use latest Gradle version (2.0), however I keep getting this message when hitting **gradle build** in terminal. Why is it asking for 1.10 version? I am new to Gradle, so I'm trying to get my head around it.

**Gradle version 1.10 is required. Current version is 2.0**

Here are my dependencies (module build.gradle file):

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    classpath fileTree(dir: 'build-libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

...and wrapper task:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = "2.0"
}
```

Also, I have set the distribution URL as follows (in the local.properties file):

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.0-all.zip
```

The final thing is that in `File->Settings->Gradle`, I selected "Use customizable gradle wrapper"

`GRADLE_HOME` is set to C:\Program Files (x86)\Gradle\gradle-2.0

The build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
        classpath fileTree(dir: 'build-libs', include: '*.jar')
    }
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = "2.0"
}
```

**UPDATE1**

As it stands i am using this Android Studio 1.1.0 with 1.1.0-rc1 plugin version

```
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0-rc1'
}
```

Gradle version is 2.3 in gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.3-all.zip
```

I have tried plugin version 1.1.0, but then it complains about *com.android.application*

**UPDATE 01/2016**

As it stands, i am using gradle 2.9 distribution in gradle - > wrapper -> gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.9-all.zip
```

and plugin is

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
```

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle file please?

Comment: Still having this problem. plugin is set to 0.12.+ and im using official release of Gradle 2.0. Cant find any traces of 1.10. Why is it asking for it :(

Comment: did you generate the wrapper for 1.10? Im having same issues. Please post an update if you got this working. I've just returned to a gradle based project and cant get it going again despite trying to regenerate the wrappers.

Comment: Nope no luck with 2.0, ive been using 1.12 for now. If i manage to find a solution i will sure post it! On thing that might help is removing .gradle folder in C:/User. I had to do it to make 1.12 working

Comment: If it helps, as it stands i am using Gradle 2.2.1, Plugin 1.0.1 and AS version 1.1 Preview 2. No problems at all.

Comment: Did you find the solution to this issue. I am facing same and can't find way through it .

Comment: @user2273146 I played around with Gradle Plugin Version and Gradle(look at the table lucas provided below). Also might want to remove .gradle folder in your /user directory or project folder, check distributionURL in gradle.wrapper.properties. Try combination from my comment 2 posts above.

Comment: @Kangars you saved me! Thank you :)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The version of Android gradle plugin needs to be compatible with the version of Gradle. Checkout the [version compatibility mapping table](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility).

[image: compatibility mapping table]

Comment: To be honest, this shows how dumb the plugin really is when it cannot use the latest version of Gradle. Seriously Google??? Sounds like the DLL hell Microsoft went through decades ago. Get with it Google.

Comment: OMG this is so stupid and annoying, Android Studio does it on every sync and automatically downgrade it for me, I am on 0.14.4 and Gradle 2.2 but it only recognizes Gradle 2.1 Anyone knows how to disable this check?

Comment: @Bob try using gradle 2.2.1, i changed gradle to 2.2 and plugin to 0.14.4 and it was asking for gradle 2.1, but changing it to 2.2.1 fixed it.

Comment: What about for Android Studio 1.0.1?

Comment: @Sauron you can use `1.0.+` for the Plugin and `2.2.1` for Gradle

Comment: After every damn Android Studio update everything is a bloody mess.
Google fails so hard on that one.

Comment: The version compatibility mapping table link got 404.

Comment: Work with Java/Google/Eclipse/Intelij is a hell!

Answer (score 64):

**Message:** "Gradle version 1.10 is required. Current version is 2.0"

**Occurs when:** Attempting to build an Android project that requires 1.10 version of Gradle while using 2.0 version of it as native.

**Solution:** Using Gradle Wrapper

**Steps:**

1. Make sure the **distributionUrl** is specified as **gradle-1.10-all.zip** at the Gradle-wrapper properties file within the Android project. The file path would be like this:

   > *MyAndroidProject/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties*
2. Run Gradle Wrapper command at the very top level of the project where the executable scripts (i.e. **gradlew** and **gradlew.bat**) are located.

   For **Unix-like** OS:

   > *./gradlew wrapper*

   For **Windows** OS:

   > *gradlew.bat wrapper*
3. Run build command with Gradle Wrapper.

   For **Unix-like** OS:

   > *./gradlew build*

   For **Windows** OS:

   > *gradlew.bat build*

Comment: This worked for me. While doing this, I had to install JDK and follow the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587751/gradle-execution-failed-for-task-processdebugmanifest

Comment: It was driving me crazy that my distributionUrl was set to the latest but the version of gradle on my machine wasn't, and gradle sync in android studio did nothing! Running './gradlew wrapper' in the terminal in android studio was exactly what i needed, it's a shame Google hasn't made that easier/more obvious...

Answer (score 16):

I fix the problem updating the gradle version within build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'
```

}

This solve my problem. I hope this would help.

Comment: with gradle 2.1 you will need     dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.+'
    }

Comment: yes, you're right, but with gradle 2.1 I would like to use 'dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.2'
    }' is better if you don't use .+ at the end.

Comment: Worked when:

dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.2'
}
I got around to the issue on my ends with swapping out 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'

Strange is that I would think the original captured 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.2'

Comment: Just in case you're using Gradle 2.1.1 then you should specify classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.+'

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the current version of Android Gradle plugin (0.12.2) works with Gradle of version not later than 1.12.

I haven't found a direct statement for that on the Tools site, there is this phrase only:

> Gradle 1.10 or 1.11 or 1.12 with the plugin 0.11.1.

But I manually tested with Gradle 2.0 and 1.2 and it does not work, so I believe this restriction from the Tools site still applies for Android Gradle plugin 0.12.2.

I would suggest to fail back to Gradle 1.12 by setting `distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-bin.zip`
in your `gradle-wrapper.properties` file.

Then just use `gradlew` as usual.

Answer (score 4):

The Android plugin requires a particular version of Gradle. The latest Android plugin version requires 1.12, the Android plugin version declared in your build requires 1.10.

Comment: It is not properly correct. The last android plugin is 0.11.1 and works with gradle 1.10-1.11-1.12.

Comment: Yea i might have to use Gradle 1.12 instead of this 2.0-rc-1 for now. My plugin is 0.11.+, i will try with 1.12 instead.

Answer (score 2):

I was following wono's method on mac and I was getting "gradlew command not found" error. Fixed issue by changing mod of gradlew file

> chmod +x gradlew

I hope this will help others

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this problem because you moved project developed using old Android studio to new Android Studio, then just create new project in new Android Studio and cross check your gradle related files with newly create project.

Answer (score 0):

**IF ABOVE FIX DO NOT WORK TRY THIS**

**You have to change this line in `build.gradle`**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
```

in

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.+'
```

**you have to change this line in your `build.gradle`**

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
```

In

```
buildTypes {
        release {
             minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
```