# Cordova 4.1.2 Android studio 1.0 bug Gradle version

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm new in Cordova and Android. I work on MAC OS Mavericks

I install Android Studio (1.0) than I create my project and import it into Android Studio. I get this error in the console : 
Gradle version 1.10 is required. Current version is 2.2.1 ...

I rood a lot of stack post but nothing work.

I try to change the gradle-wrapper properties to https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.1-all.zip but I get other errors.

```
Error:Unable to load class 'org.gradle.internal.reflect.Instantiator'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:<ul><li>Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a></li><li>The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
<a href="stopGradleDaemons">Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)</a></li></ul>In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

I also read this post [Gradle version 1.10 is required. Current version is 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24289410/gradle-version-1-10-is-required-current-version-is-2-0)

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: cordova isn't compatible with the android studio 1.0 yet, but they are working on it

Comment: What can I do than? Is there an older version of Android studio or had I do something other? How can I fixed that ? Thanks.

Comment: just don't use android studio, you don't need it for cordova development, use the cordova CLI and any editor to edit your files

Comment: OK. Thanks but I'm really new and don't have any idea of where to start. Nothing on the doc for cordova. Do you know a tuto. If I use eclipse, what must I do ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can start here http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_index.md.html or you can find some useful post here http://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/

Comment: "cordova isn't compatible with the android studio 1.0 yet, but they are working on it" - where did you find this information?