# Gradle Native Artifacts Plugin applying failed

Tags: gradle

is anyone of you experienced in [Gradle Native Artifacts Plugin](https://github.com/sgeb/gradle-native-artifacts-plugin)?

I would like to use it, but I am not able to run it even in the basic application:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://sgeb.github.io/maven_repo/"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "me.sgeb.gradle:gradle-native-artifacts-plugin:1.+"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'native-artifacts'
```

and nothing more. Will cause:

```
Download https://sgeb.github.io/maven_repo/me/sgeb/gradle/gradle-native-artifacts-plugin/1.1.0-SNAPSHOT/gradle-native-artifacts-plugin-1.1.0-20140322.203740-8.pom
Download https://sgeb.github.io/maven_repo/me/sgeb/gradle/gradle-native-artifacts-plugin/1.1.0-SNAPSHOT/gradle-native-artifacts-plugin-1.1.0-20140322.203740-8.jar

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\...\build.gradle' line: 13

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'test'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'native-artifacts']
   > Could not create plugin of type 'NativeArtifactsPlugin'.
```

Running it with *"--stacktrace"* a hint appears:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.plugins.PluginInstantiationException: Could not create plugin of type 'NativeArtifactsPlugin'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry.loadPlugin(DefaultPluginRegistry.java:67)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.providePlugin(DefaultPluginContainer.java:187)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.addPluginInternal(DefaultPluginContainer.java:137)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.apply(DefaultPluginContainer.java:103)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyPlugin(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:115)
        ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/model/ModelRules
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DependencyInjectingInstantiator.selectConstructor(DependencyInjectingInstantiator.java:83)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DependencyInjectingInstantiator.newInstance(DependencyInjectingInstantiator.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry.loadPlugin(DefaultPluginRegistry.java:65)
        ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.model.ModelRules
        ... 47 more
```

Runs with *"--info"* nor *"--debug"* didn't come up with anything new...

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestion?

Thank you!

Comment: What version of gradle are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, gradle 2.1 [isn't supported](https://github.com/sgeb/gradle-native-artifacts-plugin/issues/3#issuecomment-55508347).

You may downgrade to [gradle 1.11](https://github.com/sgeb/gradle-native-artifacts-plugin/blob/master/build.gradle#L121) or you may take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24832874/2286990).