# After importing eclipse project to android studio 1.4 ,getting Gradle plugin error

Tags: android, gradle

Error:(1, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':App Lite'.

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
>   Gradle version 1.10 is required. Current version is 2.4. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /home/AppLite/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-1.10-all.zip

Comment: I am new to android studio, this is the mine first migrating project.

Comment: No problem .Most welcome . Did you find ````build.gradle ````

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24832874/5099964

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the gradle-plugin for Android and gradle version.
They are different. You can find more info about the android plugin [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/plugin-for-gradle.html)

With the `classpath` inside your gradle files, you set the version of the **android plugin for Gradle**.

Change your `classpath` using:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
```

In the `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file you set the version of the **Gradle**. For example the 2.4 version.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip
```