# How to import AndroidResideMenu in Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I tried to import the AndroidResideMenu (File -> Import Project -> build.gradle from ResideMenuDemo-folder) in Android Studio (version 0.8.9).

The demo is not working because Android Studio says:
„You are using an unsupported version of Gradle. Please use version 1.12“.

I don't know how to change the gradle version.

There are a lot solutions out there maybe to change:

```
dependencies {
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
}
```

in build.gradle but it does not work for me.

Thanks in advance
Florian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay attention:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
```

This is the **gradle plugin for Android**.
Now you can use the 0.12.2 with gradle 1.12.

**There is a relation between gradle-plugin and the gradle version.**

You can check this link for all cases: [Android Studio Gradle issue upgrading to version 0.5.0 - Gradle Migrating From 0.8 to 0.9 - Also Android Studio upgrade to 0.8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252956/android-studio-gradle-issue-upgrading-to-version-0-5-0-gradle-migrating-from-0/22256954#22256954)

**Gradle 1.12** is the version of Gradle used by your project.
You can change the version in this file:

*rootProject/gradle / wrapper / gradle-wrapper.propertie*s

changing this key:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriele. That's my problem. There is no gradle-folder in my project-folder. I searched my computer for the gradle-wrapper.properties and found one file. But this file seems to be the main-gradle file and its not located in my project-folder. I downloaded the code from (https://github.com/SpecialCyCi/AndroidResideMenu) and selected the build.gradle file in the main-directory (AndroidResideMenu) in the Import Project dialog.