# Gradle version 1.10 is required. Current version is 2.2.1. error(20,0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'buildTypes()'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-build

I got the error when i importing existing project to android studio.below i attached a screenshots of error message..
[image]

We are using android studio version 1.2.2. and Our System is Windows 7 32 bit

```
Error:Gradle version 1.10 is required. Current version is 2.2.1.
```

Please Guide to us.

Comment: Which version of gradle and gradle plugin your are using?

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of gradle and gradle plugin used in your project.

In your `build.gradle` (this is the gradle plugin version) you can use:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {  
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}
```

In `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` (this is the gradle version)

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip
```

There is a relation between gradle-plugin and the gradle version, and they need to be compatible.

Check these links for a full version compatibility mapping table:

- [official link](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility)
- [my stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252956/android-studio-gradle-issue-upgrading-to-version-0-5-0-gradle-migrating-from-0/22256954#22256954)