# Android Studio, gradle plugin and gradle version information missing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

It seems this is not updated anymore:

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility

Where can I find this now?

Comment: what exactly are you looking for ?

Comment: Version dependency Android Studio, Gradle plugin and Gradle. What version is valid for what release.

Comment: I didn't find any official doc updated. Here a not-official recap.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252956/android-studio-gradle-issue-upgrading-to-version-0-5-0-gradle-migrating-from-0/22256954#22256954

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the closest result I could get.
https://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/gradle-plugin.html
Hope this helps.